# Can i downgrade android app signature from V3 to V2 (or v3 to v1)?

Tags: android, apk, signature

for some reason, i had to switch signature v3 to v2 (or v1), the problem is there is already many users installed v3 apk ,can v2 (or v1) apk overwrite v3 installed apk?

Comment: Just to clarify the question, do you want to force the users who have already installed v3 version of your app to roll back to v2 or v1?

Comment: Updating an app that uses v3 signature by an app that uses v1 should be not possible because those platforms that support v3 AFAIK do no longer accept a v1 signature only. But the question remains for v3 -> v2. I never read something that the update check considers the signature version, only if key rotation is used the version should have an impact but that is just my guess.

Comment: @HardikKhandelwal yes ,newer app will only have v2 or v1 signature

Comment: after some test (~20 devices，7~8 brand) ，it seems v1 overwrite v3 is always ok ,v2 overwrite v3 is always fail